# How can I generate unique key values for records in a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I assign surrogate keys when inserting records in a BigQuery table?
Something like using Sequence to generate unique values or NextVal ?

Comment: This is pretty broad, as there is a lot of ways to do this. There's nothing automated into BQ though, so you have to code something yourself to generate that unique value.

Answer (score 13):

If you are looking to generate surrogate key values in BigQuery then it is best to avoid the ROW_NUMBER OVER () option and its variants. To quote the BigQuery post about surrogate keys:

> To implement ROW_NUMBER(), BigQuery needs to sort values at the root
>   node of the execution tree, which is limited by the amount of memory
>   in one execution node.

This will always cause you to run into issues when you have even a mild amount of records.

There are two alternatives:

**Option 1 - GENERATE_UUID()**

Since a surrogate key has no business meaning and is just a unique key generated to be used in the data warehouse you can simply generate them using the `GENERATE_UUID()` function call in BigQuery. This gives you a universally unique UUID which you can use as a surrogate key value.

One drawback is that this key will be 32 bites instead of an 8 byte INT64 value. So if you have a massive amount of records this could increase the storage size of your data.

**Option 2 - Generate a unique Hash**

The second option is to use a hash function to generate a unique has. This is a little more involved as you would need to find the combination of columns and or random other input to make sure you can never generate the same value twice.

Some hash functions will also output a 32 byte value so you wont save on storage but the FARM_FINGERPRINT() hash function will output an INT64 value which could save some storage. You could thus utilise options 1 and option 2 to generate a unique integer surrogate key by doing the following:
`FARM_FINGERPRINT(GENERATE_UUID())`

Comment: Best solution in this thread i believe. Linking the related post from Google here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/bigquery-and-surrogate-keys-practical-approach

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach that generates a unique integer ID for each row, with the IDs sorted according to some value in the source datasaet, in this case a timestamp:

```
SELECT
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp) unique_id,
  title
FROM
  [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
LIMIT 1000
```

An alternative is to generate the unique identifiers randomly:

```
SELECT 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY random) unique_id,
    RAND() random,
    title
FROM
    [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
LIMIT 1000
```

To attach these values at insert time, load your source data into a BigQuery table, then modify the code above to select from that table (instead of wikipedia) and save the results.

Comment: Both queries failed with Error: "Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Sort operator used for OVER(ORDER BY) used too much memory.."   ORDER BY operation is quite expensive and cannot be processed in parallel. So there were too many rows to hold in memory on a single node.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this

```
SELECT
   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()) 
   + 
   (
      SELECT
         MAX(surrogate_key)
      FROM
         dimension_table ) AS surrogate_key,
   business_key,
   attribute1,
   attributen,
   CURRENT_DATE AS start_date, 
   null as end_date,   
   true AS is_current
FROM
  source_table
```

- nb : last 3 elements are scd2 fields and requires new style SQL
  syntax to work
- nb2 : if you ORDER BY in Row_number, BigQuery will    probably throw
  a too hard error because ORDER BY cannot be    parallelised